# Android M - MediaRecorder start failed

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder

Samsung galaxy S6 edge 6.0.1 works fine, so maybe Android M is not the factor here.

First off, the Android 6.0+ permissions are given, so that's not the case .

Here it is :

```
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
        //нужно проверять пермишны
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || 
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                   new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                        PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);           

        }
    }
```

I've tested my app on other devices and it works fine, but on Nexus 5 (hammerhead) I've got an error when MediaRecorder.start() is called and I don't know much what to do with that.

The stacktrace is as simple as :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
    at com.vladdrummer.headsup.ScreenVideoRecorder.record(ScreenVideoRecorder.java:94)
```

So, not too much info. Here's the code, but keep in mind , it **Works** on other devices

```
private  Camera camera;
...
 camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                  camera.startPreview();
                  isPrepared = prepareVideoRecorder();
..
    private boolean prepareVideoRecorder() {
        try{

        camera.unlock();

        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
            .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        String path = A.getRawGameVideoPath();//4 debug purposes
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(path);
        mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        try {
          mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          release();
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      }

      public void record(){
          if (isPrepared){        
          mediaRecorder.start(); // Here where it crashes on Android M
          }
      }
```

Of course, it may be crashing on other devices as well, I tested it on 3 devices only

Answer (score 0):

For android M You need to add Runtime Permission like `Camera,Audio`
Try This it may be help to you

```
private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST = 11;
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
if (mContext.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
} else {
    Log.d("TAG", "Already granted access");
    initializeView(v);
}
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST: {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Permission Granted");
            initializeView(v);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", "Permission Failed");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "You must allow permission record audio to your mobile device.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            getActivity().finish();
        }
    }
    // Add additional cases for other permissions you may have asked for
}
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's not the case, I've given that permissions  in Runtime

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || 
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
    ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.INTERNET)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
               new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,Manifest.permission.INTERNET,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    0);
    }
}
```