# unknown permission android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-mediarecorder

Suddenly in my logs in "warn" I've found this :

```
unknown permission android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO
```

And this happened on a device that fails to do a `MediaRecorder.start()` method with simple and uninformative "start fails" error message.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
    at com.vladdrummer.headsup.ScreenVideoRecorder.record(ScreenVideoRecorder.java:94)
```

App is working on many devices, but some have this kind of a problem - it fails to start, although , preparing went fine

So, may be theese two errors are connected? what should I do with "unknown permission android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO" ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no permission as

```
android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO
```

See [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

Ideally you should be using these permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Also manifest should have

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera"/>
```

Comment: Well, really, that's a made-up permission, now I remember that! :) but still MediaRecorder fail to start :(

Comment: Please post your log from logcat

Comment: What do you have at `ScreenVideoRecorder.java`. Please post that code.

Comment: it's here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651356/android-m-mediarecorder-start-failed/